# Spring migration to 5.0.0 replacing deprecated WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is erroneous

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I update the Spring Framework `4.3.9.RELEASE` to `5.0.0.RELEASE` and in my surprise, the class [WebMvcConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html) has been marked as deprecated since the 5.0 version. As the documentation says:

> **Deprecated.**
>
> as of 5.0 WebMvcConfigurer has default methods (made possible by a Java 8 baseline) and can be implemented directly without the need for this adapter

I have tried to change the class definition to implement [WebMvcConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html).

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "net.nichar.app")
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH");
    }
}
```

I import the following artifacts using Maven, which are all of the same version:

- spring-core
- spring-web
- spring-webmvc
- spring-orm

Although I followed the Spring doumention, I must do something wrong because as soon as I try to run the application, an error is thrown:

> 2017-10-11 22:42:03 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
>
> Oct 11, 2017 10:42:03 ODP. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
>   SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
>       at ......

Would you help me to fix it? Feel free to require more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has nothing to do with `WebMvcConfigurer` (you should remove that part from your question, since it will be misleading to others).

The exception points to Jackson, you're most likely not using the right Jackson version:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
```

Spring Framework 5 requires Jackson 2.9+, [as stated in the migration documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-to-Spring-Framework-5.x).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. My assumption about WebMvcConfigurer was based on the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter deprecation. That's where my confusion has started.